# HTML Webform with VBScript keeps giving error of Parameter was not supplied

Tags: html, sql, vbscript

I am working on a web form using HTML and VBScripting in order to submit the form to the database. If the whole form is filled out, the values go find in a database, but if some of the values are missing, I keep getting an error saying that the parameter is not supplied.

What I am trying to do, is a user is going to fill out a form, some of the fields are not required so when it is submitted to the database, I am looking for a null value to go in. Below is the code I am using for different parts:

```
    <%
Dim MM_editAction
MM_editAction = CStr(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))
If (Request.QueryString <> "") Then
  MM_editAction = MM_editAction & "?" &         Server.HTMLEncode(Request.QueryString)
End If

' boolean to abort record edit
Dim MM_abortEdit
MM_abortEdit = false
%>
 <%
' IIf implementation
 Function MM_IIf(condition, ifTrue, ifFalse)
  If condition = "" Then
    MM_IIf = ifFalse
  Else
    MM_IIf = ifTrue
  End If
End Function
%>
<%
 If (CStr(Request("MM_insert")) = "form1") Then
  If (Not MM_abortEdit) Then
' execute the insert
Dim MM_editCmd

Set MM_editCmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection = MM_databaseLive_STRING
MM_editCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table.Table (LName, FName, Email, Employee_ID, Two_Years_Exp, BSN, NSG_Grad_Yr, Est_NSG_School, Highest_Degree, APN, APN_Yes, Other_Degree_Nursing, Other_Degree_Nursing_Yes, Other_Degree_Nursing_Mth, Other_Degree_Nursing_Year, Other_Degree_Nursing_School, Highest_Degree_NN, NSG_Certification, Hire_Yr, NSG_Years, Categories, Items) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 
MM_editCmd.Prepared = true
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param1", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("LName")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param2", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("FName")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param3", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("email")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param4", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Phone")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param7", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Two_Years_Exp")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param8", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("BSN")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param9", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("NSG_Grad_Yr")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param10", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Est_NSG_School")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param11", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Highest_Degree")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param12", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("APN")) ' adVarWChar
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param13", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("APN_Yes")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param14", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Other_Degree_Nursing"))
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param15", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Other_Degree_Nursing_Yes"))
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param16", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Other_Degree_Nursing_Mth"))
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param17", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Other_Degree_Nursing_Year"))
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param18", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Other_Degree_Nursing_School")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param19", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Highest_Degree_NN"))
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param20", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("NSG_Certification")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param21", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Hire_Yr")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param22", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("NSG_Years")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param5", 202, 1, 255,  Request.Form("categories")) 
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param6", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("items")) 
MM_editCmd.Execute
MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection.Close

' append the query string to the redirect URL
Dim MM_editRedirectUrl
MM_editRedirectUrl = "thank-you.asp"
If (Request.QueryString <> "") Then
  If (InStr(1, MM_editRedirectUrl, "?", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
    MM_editRedirectUrl = MM_editRedirectUrl & "?" & Request.QueryString
  Else
    MM_editRedirectUrl = MM_editRedirectUrl & "&" & Request.QueryString
  End If
End If
Response.Redirect(MM_editRedirectUrl)
  End If
End If
%>
```

Comment: I found out something else while troubleshooting. I am using combo boxes where a user can select more than one answer. If they don't select anything, it seems to be throwing an error. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

why using vbs script for that when its 100% less complicated with javascript?
vbs is similar to javascript because both are executed on client side.

use javascript:

```
if(form.yourinput.value == '') { 
    document.getElementById('yourinputerrorid').innerHTML="empty";
    form.yourinput.focus(); 
    document.getElementById("yourinput").className = 'your new class';
}
```

Comment: Hi There, I inherited this project with the VBScript already being used and accepted. Basically I am just trying to figure out how I can always make it submit. Right now, if some of the questions do not apply and they are left unanswered, it throws an error saying it is expecting something.

Comment: i'm not really good but you can try this. if u set a empty value your form should submit
If IsNull(value) Then
   var = " "
End If

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **MM_IIf** function in **your code** above or create a new function to check null value.

**Use MM_IIf function**

```
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param1", 202, 1, 255, MM_IIF(Request.Form("LName"),Request.Form("LName"),null))
```

**New Function**

```
<%
' check null value
Function MM_CheckNull(condition)
  If condition = "" Then
    MM_CheckNull = null
  Else
    MM_CheckNull = condition
  End If
End Function
%>

MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param1", 202, 1, 255, MM_CheckNull(Request.Form("LName")))
```